# How to drag and rotate multiple objects using Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d

In order to find the best relative position for each object, if I want to move, rotate multiple objects like 10 objects by clicking and dragging objects using Three.js, are there any other efficient ways to do that? I found the real example ((https://codepen.io/OpherV/pen/YXwwNR). However, it seems good for just 1 or 2 objects. Could you please advise any examples or solutions using Three.js?

Thanks a lot.

```js
/**
 * Provides requestAnimationFrame in a cross browser way.
 * @author paulirish / http://paulirish.com/
 */

if (!window.requestAnimationFrame) {

  window.requestAnimationFrame = (function() {

    return window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
      window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
      window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
      window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
      function( /* function FrameRequestCallback */ callback, /* DOMElement Element */ element) {

        window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);

      };

  })();

}
   var container, stats;

            var camera, scene, renderer;

            var cube, plane;

            var targetRotationX = 0.5;
            var targetRotationOnMouseDownX = 0;

            var targetRotationY = 0.2;
            var targetRotationOnMouseDownY = 0;

            var mouseX = 0;
            var mouseXOnMouseDown = 0;

            var mouseY = 0;
            var mouseYOnMouseDown = 0;

            var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
            var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

            var slowingFactor = 0.25;

            init();
            animate();

            function init() {

                container = document.createElement( 'div' );
                document.body.appendChild( container );

                scene = new THREE.Scene();

                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );
                camera.position.y = 150;
                camera.position.z = 500;
                scene.add( camera );

                var materials = [];

                for ( var i = 0; i < 6; i ++ ) {

                    materials.push( new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: Math.random() * 0xffffff } ) );

                }

                cube = new THREE.Mesh(  new THREE.BoxGeometry( 200, 200, 200 ) , new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials) );
                cube.position.y = 150;
                cube.overdraw = true;
                scene.add( cube );              
                            
                            
                            
                            

                plane = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 200, 200 ), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xe0e0e0 } ) );
                plane.rotation.x = - 90 * ( Math.PI / 180 );
                plane.overdraw = true;

                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

                container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

                stats = new Stats();
                stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
                stats.domElement.style.top = '0px';
                container.appendChild( stats.domElement );

                document.addEventListener( 'mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false );
            }

            function onDocumentMouseDown( event ) {

                event.preventDefault();

                document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );
                document.addEventListener( 'mouseup', onDocumentMouseUp, false );
                document.addEventListener( 'mouseout', onDocumentMouseOut, false );

                mouseXOnMouseDown = event.clientX - windowHalfX;
                targetRotationOnMouseDownX = targetRotationX;

                mouseYOnMouseDown = event.clientY - windowHalfY;
                targetRotationOnMouseDownY = targetRotationY;
            }

            function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {

                mouseX = event.clientX - windowHalfX;

                targetRotationX = ( mouseX - mouseXOnMouseDown ) * 0.00025;

                mouseY = event.clientY - windowHalfY;

                targetRotationY = ( mouseY - mouseYOnMouseDown ) * 0.00025;
            }

            function onDocumentMouseUp( event ) {

                document.removeEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );
                document.removeEventListener( 'mouseup', onDocumentMouseUp, false );
                document.removeEventListener( 'mouseout', onDocumentMouseOut, false );
            }

            function onDocumentMouseOut( event ) {

                document.removeEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );
                document.removeEventListener( 'mouseup', onDocumentMouseUp, false );
                document.removeEventListener( 'mouseout', onDocumentMouseOut, false );
            }


            function animate() {

                requestAnimationFrame( animate );

                render();
                stats.update();

            }

            function render() {

                rotateAroundWorldAxis(cube, new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0), targetRotationX);
                rotateAroundWorldAxis(cube, new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0), targetRotationY);
              
                targetRotationY = targetRotationY * (1 - slowingFactor);
                targetRotationX = targetRotationX * (1 - slowingFactor);
                renderer.render( scene, camera );

            }

            function rotateAroundObjectAxis(object, axis, radians) {
                var rotationMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4();

                rotationMatrix.makeRotationAxis(axis.normalize(), radians);
                object.matrix.multiply(rotationMatrix);
                object.rotation.setFromRotationMatrix( object.matrix );

            }

          function rotateAroundWorldAxis( object, axis, radians ) {

              var rotationMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4();

              rotationMatrix.makeRotationAxis( axis.normalize(), radians );
              rotationMatrix.multiply( object.matrix );                       // pre-multiply
              object.matrix = rotationMatrix;
              object.rotation.setFromRotationMatrix( object.matrix );
          }
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Monospace;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.caption{
  padding: 1rem;
  color: white;
  background: black;
  font-size: 2rem;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>CodePen - Object drag rotation in Three.js</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/loaders/OBJLoader.js"></script>

    <script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>


<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/stats.js/r11/Stats.min.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
<div class="caption">Drag to rotate</div>
<!-- partial -->
 

  


</body>
<script src="./script.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Why not just use the normal `OrbitControls` functionality?

Comment: Thanks for your input. OrbitControls is used to rotate a group of objects at one time. But, I'm wondering how to drag and rotate each object at different angles in the same scene. Please correct me if I have any misunderstanding.